# What does "Hungarian" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, figurative

I think it’s a figurative usage as a reminder of blood, but not for sure. Why is the word *Hungarian* used here?

(*He* is a professional pianist who holds lessons open to the public.)

> When I told him that one of the students had likened it to an energy radiating from his hands into theirs, he laughed and offered his own image: “I give them a blood transfusion right there on stage! After all, I’m Hungarian.” (*The Piano Shop on the Left Bank* by Thad Carhart)

Comment: I don't disagree with Andrew's answer, but I think decoding this usage is just *too localised*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably to do with his identifying Hungary with Transylvania and the Count Dracula myth. He is humorously indicating that Hungarians are vampires. (I suppose that's acceptable as he's Hungarian: I wouldn't recommend people who are not from that country trying that.)

Comment: Transylvania is in Romania. That's not Hungary.

Comment: I know that. I've adjusted the answer.

Comment: Forgive my nitpickiness. I realise Transylvania was still part of Hungary when Dracula was written, I figured that some other smartalec would down vote you if you didn't justify it.

Comment: Bela Legosi, the actor who most famous brought Count Dracula to life -- or un-dead-ness at least -- on the silver screen, was Hungarian.

Comment: @MattЭллен The thing is, most of the world outside Europe thinks that either Transylvania is Romania or that it was always part of Romania. In fact, Transylvania has little to nothing to do with Romania apart from the administrative boundaries having been adjusted after the 1st World War. For almost a thousand years, Transylvania was either part of or maintained a very strong relationship with Hungary; its culture is predominantly Hungarian and Saxon -- historically, few Romanian people have lived there (although their number admittedly increased over time, esp. after the 18th century).